# Create a Linked Server Using a Windows Account in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

There are multiple applications on SQL Server which I am trying to connect to from a Single SQL Server. Instead of creating multiple SQL User ID we thought of creating a single Windows Service Account and use that to connect to other SQL Servers.

The issue is I dont know if I can configure a Linked Server to take the credentials of a Windows Service account.

Points:

1. Access has been given to the Windows user account
2. SQL Servers are on Different domains

Is there a best approach to read from multiple sources within the organization other than linked servers?

Update:

Please find below code I am trying to use to create a Linked Server:

```
USE [master]
GO

EXEC sp_addlinkedserver     
     @server=N'serverinstance',   
     @srvproduct=N'',  
     @provider=N'SQLNCLI',   
     @datasrc=N'serverinstance.domain.local'; 

GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname = N'serverinstance'
                                , @useself = N'TRUE'
                                , @locallogin = N'Domain\NTAccount' 
                              --, @rmtuser = N'user'
                              --, @rmtpassword = N'pass'
GO
```

The linked server still fails. I do not want to use any SQL Server User Auth.

Comment: See this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addlinkedsrvlogin-transact-sql

Comment: Can anyone validate the way i am trying to add the Linked Server

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to setup a trust between the 2 domains and make sure the firewall is letting you access the linked server.

Answer (score -1):

It can be either.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188477(v=sql.105).aspx

Authentication works the same regardless of if you use Sql or NT Domain authentication.

Comment: He is specifically asking to use NT account for Linked Server login. The page you linked to states: "Remote User

    Use the remote user to map users not defined in Local login. The Remote User must be a **SQL Server Authentication login** on the remote server."

Comment: The NT account has been given permissions on the box.Linked server is not able to connect when using NT credentials.

Comment: It is basically the same thing.  Insure you are doing windows based login correctly.  Then switch it to the other NT account.  You most likely have not identified the user correctly to the Sql server.  My link pointed to an example of how it works or that it works.  It does not exactly match the OP's question.  But if you can do that you should be able to do what he seeks.  Make sure you can get that working properly first, then switch it to the exact methods you seek to use.  I believe you have a domain related issue not a Sql issue.

Comment: My Take:
Even if we try to connect using a NT account there should always be a SQLServer user account that needs to be mapped to the NT account to impersonate the access. Sole access to an NT account will not work to configure a Linked Server

Comment: I have done this previously without use of any Sql Server account.  There is no sql account requirement for doing this.  Take this in steps.  I suspect most likely the trust connection between domains is not setup right.  Cross link two Sql servers on the same domain.  Insure you have the commands down.  It is best to do this command line not from the gui it gives you more error info.  Confirm your have a trust configuration between domains with a method that has nothing to do with Sql.  Then put the pieces together and try the full challenge you are attempting to resolve.